# Codeigniter get form_open value in controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a tiny CI form, like following:

```
<div class="box_txt">
<?php $attributes = array('clock_id' => $clock['id']); ?> 
<?php echo form_open('clock/start', $attributes) ?>
      <input type="submit" value="Start" />
      </form>
 </div>
```

And it generates a from with the folowing openning:

```
<form action="../clock/start" clock_id="123" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

I would really need to know what's the correct way to capture the `clock_id` in controller's function?

Comment: are you sure about clock_id attribute for html form tag?

Comment: Absolutely. That's a copy/paste from source code viewed in browser. If there is a better way to pass this single hidden value to the controler, I would be glad to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting clock_id as a form attribute, you should consider using a hidden input tag:

```
<input type='hidden' name='clock_id' value='<?php echo $clock["id"]; ?>'/>
```

then you can handle it using `$this->input->post('clock_id')`

Otherwise, if you really want to stick to your code, you could use jquery to get the attribute and send an ajax request:

```
var clock_id = $('form').attr('clock_id');

$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var type = $(this).attr('method');
    var data = $(this).serialize() + '&clock_id=' + clock_id
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success:function(response){ /* handle response */}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clock_id` value on the form tag won't be sent with a form submit, as it's not a form element.  Instead, you should do the following to use a hidden field:

```
echo form_hidden('clock_id', $clock['id']);
```

That will create a hidden field within your form, with the name 'clock_id' and the value, in this case, '123'

Answer (score 1):

If you need clock_id in controller,try this code.

```
<div class="box_txt">

    <?php echo form_open('clock/start') ?>
         <input type="hidden" name="clock_id" value="123" />
         <input type="submit" value="Start" />
     <?php echo form_close() ?>

     </div>
```

Controller:

```
function start()
{
    $clock_id = $this->input->post('clock_id');
}
```